# UISearchController's shadow floats over the search bar

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios9, xcode7

I try to implement a simple search feature (with swift2 and xcode 7), the feature itself works fine but UI is broken. Looks like the SearchController's shadow (or whatever its name) floats over the search bar.

[image]

Update: once I set a `SearchBar.Top` constraint to `-10` and check the `Remove at build time` it looks like that (which is also not so good):

[image]

Comment: set the layout constraints properly

Comment: Of which control exactly?